# sqlx installation fails due to mismatched types

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-sqlx

I'm installing [sqlx](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx) on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx sqlx-cli
```

I get the error

```
 error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> sqlx-cli/src/opt.rs:8:20
  |
8 |     #[clap(short = "D", long)]
  |                    ^^^ expected `char`, found `&str`
```

````
$ rustc --explain E0308                                                                                   
    
    Expected type did not match the received type.
    
    Erroneous code example:
    
    ```
    let x: i32 = "I am not a number!";
    //     ~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //      |             |
    //      |    initializing expression;
    //      |    compiler infers type `&str`
    //      |
    //    type `i32` assigned to variable `x`
    ```
    
    This error occurs when the compiler is unable to infer the concrete type of a
    variable. It can occur in several cases, the most common being a mismatch
    between two types: the type the author explicitly assigned, and the type the
    compiler inferred.
````

```
$ rustc --version                                                                                         
    rustc 1.47.0 (18bf6b4f0 2020-10-07)

$ cargo --version                                                                                                 
    cargo 1.47.0 (f3c7e066a 2020-08-28)
```

[The full logs](https://gist.github.com/iapicca/39424fc7f7e17336751c1b9b7184c90c)

How can I solve the error and complete the installation?

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/730)

Comment: `"D"` defines a _string_ which just happens to contain a single character. Short options in Clap are `char`, which is defined with simple quotes: `'D'`.

Comment: this error is the output of "cargo install --git https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx sqlx-cli" not of my application, I'm not sure how am I supposed to complete that installation

Comment: Then this is a bug in `sqlx-cli`, you will need to file a bug with them and/or use a [released version](https://crates.io/crates/sqlx-cli) with `cargo install sqlx-cli`.

Comment: I've already linked the github issue in my question (bottom), I'm looking for a workaround to get me going while the issue is being addressed

Comment: apparently I'm not the only one experiencing the issue
https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/730#issuecomment-707733077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running

```
cargo install -f --git https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx sqlx-cli
```

instead of

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx sqlx-cli
```

fixes the issue

[source](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/730#issuecomment-710677072)